# How to get to root cause of Tornado "BadYieldError: yielded unknown object None"

Tags: python, tornado, coroutine

The code stub that gets the error at the second yield is below: here ostream is a `tornado.process.Subprocess.STREAM` and `cl` is a list of `websocket.WebSocketHandlers and the function whose body the`s contains has the decorators `@web.asynchronous` and `@gen.coroutine`  :

```
while True:
   data = yield self.ostream.read_until(b'CCMM\n')
   if data:
      data=data[:-1]+" "+str(cntr)
      for c in cl:
         yield c.write_message(json.dumps({"data":data}))
```

I didn't get this error on tornado 4.3 but I get this error on a machine where tornado version was 4.0: I assume the incoming byte sequence on the ostream is identical because the python code being popen'ed is identical.

I have just started playing with tornado and was wondering how to debug why this seems to be an issue on 4.0 but not 4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [docs for WebSocketHandler.write_message](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html#tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler.write_message).

> Changed in version 4.3: Returns a Future which can be used for flow control.

Prior to version 4.3, `write_message` returned None, so it could not be used with `yield`. If your application needs flow control on outgoing websocket messages, it requires Tornado 4.3 or newer.